# What is the reason for the name *left* coset?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be a group and let $H \leq G$ be a subgroup. It seems that it is now standard to call the cosets 
$$gH=\{gh \ | h \in H \}$$ the *left cosets* of $H$ in $G$. I have to admit to being slightly annoyed with this convention: these are the orbits for the *right* action of $H$ on $G$. Therefore I am perpetually tempted to refer to them as right cosets. Is there a second good reason (I happily admit convention is a very good reason) for calling these left cosets? (The fact that the "g" is written on the left does not count, as far as I am concerned).

Comment: It may not count, but it’s obviously the reason for the terminology.

Comment: The element $g$ is multiplying on the **left**. Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: During the Algebra course in my freshman year, I was told that what we called *left coset* was also called *right coset* by some people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't think of them as the orbits of the right action of $H$ on $G$. The set of left cosets itself admits a natural left $G$-action, and every transitive left $G$-action arises in this way.